# Postfix cant fix open relay

Tags: linux, email, postfix, smtp

postfix configuration:

```
~ # postconf -n | grep mynetworks
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mynetworks_style = host
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_sender_login_mismatch, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unlisted_sender, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject
```

But contrary to my expectations the postfix Server accepts EVERYTHING from non-existing domains, wrong domains to adresses it is definetely not responsible for and therefore is a open relay.

```
{} ~ telnet SERVER 25
Trying IP...
Connected to SERVER.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 SERVER ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
HELO google.de
250 SERVER
MAIL FROM: root@facebook.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: root@pizza.com
250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Subject: Test
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4AB737C1039
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

As you can see this clearly violates multiple rules defined in the postfix configuration.

Q: Why and how do I fix this?

complete postfix config:

```
~ # postconf -n                                                                                                                                                                                
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
home_mailbox = Mail/Inbox/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
mydestination = $myhostname, SERVER, localhost.DOMAIN, localhost
myhostname = SERVER
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/SERVER/cert.pem
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname SOOS ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_sender_login_mismatch, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unlisted_sender, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/SERVER/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, LOW, EXP, MEDIUM, ADH, AECDH, MD5, DSS, ECDSA, CAMELLIA128, 3DES, CAMELLIA256, RSA+AES, eNULL
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/SERVER/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Your listening interface isn't bound to `lo/127.0.0.1`

```
inet_interfaces = all
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You may want to add a note _why_ you think that was the reason for the OP's problem.

Comment: No, even if I set 
`inet_interfaces = loopback-only`
it behaves the same

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you tail the mail.log while you are doing your telnet test to confirm that the *apparent* IP address you are connecting from is not in fact in your network.  If it is, the first rule in the relay restrictions will permit the traffic.

As an example, a configuration change on our firewall masked the source IP of the peer connection.  This made *all* connections appear to be in-network.  Nothing in the postfix configuration even changed.  The mail log showed all traffic to originate from the firewall itself.  Bad day for everyone.

With respect to setting the interface to localhost, this would mean that you are also connecting from localhost as well.  Per the rules specified, relaying *would* be allowed in that case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).